# Given a list, print the no of times each integer in a list occurred

Tags: python

For example, L = [1,2,2,3,4,9]
Expected output:
1 occurred 1 times
2 occurred 2 times
3 occurred 1 times
4 occurred 1 times
9 occurred 1 times

Comment: collections.Counter(l)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, we expect you to do your research before posting a question. Searching [your question exactly](https://www.google.com/search?q=print+the+no+of+times+each+integer+in+a+list+occurred) will get you what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import collections

for k, freq in collections.Counter(L).items():
    print(f"{k} occurred {freq} times")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print these out as strings:

```
for i in set(L):
    print(f"{i} occurred {L.count(i)} times"
```

If you want to store these counts to use later in the code, use a dictionary:
`d = {i: L.count(i) for i in set(L)`

Comment: These are both unnecessarily inefficient implementations